# How can I choose an element in dynamic drop list?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am writing a selenium test in Java and I'm unable to select server (for example "CORAL")  from the drop down list.

This is the html:

```
  <div id="listBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" style="overflow: hidden; background-color: transparent; border: medium none; position: absolute; display: none; width: 355px; height: 307px; left: 12px; top: 64px;">
<div id="innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listbox jqx-listbox-sandbox jqx-reset jqx-reset-sandbox jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-sandbox jqx-widget jqx-widget-sandbox jqx-widget-content jqx-widget-content-sandbox jqx-disableselect jqx-popup jqx-popup-sandbox" style="width: 330px; height: 282px; position: absolute; z-index: 2147483647; top: 0px; left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; opacity: 1;" aria-multiselectable="false" role="listbox">
<div style="-webkit-appearance: none; background: transparent; outline: none; width:100%; height: 100%; align:left; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; valign:top; position: relative;">
<div style="-webkit-appearance: none; border: none; background: transparent; outline: none; width:100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; align:left; left: 0px; top: 0px; valign:top; position: relative;">
<div id="listBoxContentinnerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; outline: medium none; border: medium none; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute; width: 311px; height: 280px;">
<div style="outline: 0px none; overflow: hidden; width: 330px; position: relative; height: 564px;">
<div id="listitem0innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" aria-selected="true">
<span class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-listitem-state-normal-sandbox jqx-item jqx-item-sandbox jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-sandbox jqx-listitem-state-selected jqx-listitem-state-selected-sandbox jqx-fill-state-pressed jqx-fill-state-pressed-sandbox" style="display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 301px;">172.29.45.28</span>
</div>
<div id="listitem1innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 24px; left: 0px;">
<span class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-listitem-state-normal-sandbox jqx-item jqx-item-sandbox jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-sandbox" style="display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 301px;">192.168.155.98</span>
</div>
<div id="listitem2innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 48px; left: 0px;">
<span class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-listitem-state-normal-sandbox jqx-item jqx-item-sandbox jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-sandbox" style="display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 301px;">192.168.203.165</span>
</div>
<div id="listitem3innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 72px; left: 0px;">
<span class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-listitem-state-normal-sandbox jqx-item jqx-item-sandbox jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-sandbox" style="display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 301px;">192.168.203.21</span>
</div>
<div id="listitem4innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 96px; left: 0px;">
<span class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-listitem-state-normal-sandbox jqx-item jqx-item-sandbox jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-sandbox" style="display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 301px;">192.168.99.94</span>
</div>
<div id="listitem5innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 120px; left: 0px;">
<span class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-listitem-state-normal-sandbox jqx-item jqx-item-sandbox jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-sandbox" style="display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 301px;">Alexey</span>
</div>
<div id="listitem6innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 144px; left: 0px;">
<span class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-listitem-state-normal-sandbox jqx-item jqx-item-sandbox jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-sandbox" style="display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 301px;">Anton</span>
</div>
<div id="listitem7innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 168px; left: 0px;">
<span class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-listitem-state-normal-sandbox jqx-item jqx-item-sandbox jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-sandbox" style="display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 301px;">Anton origin issue env</span>
</div>
<div id="listitem8innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 192px; left: 0px;">
<span class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-listitem-state-normal-sandbox jqx-item jqx-item-sandbox jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-sandbox" style="display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 301px;">CORAL</span>
</div>
<div id="listitem9innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 216px; left: 0px;">
<div id="listitem10innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 240px; left: 0px;">
<div id="listitem11innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 576px; left: 0px;">
<span class="" style="display: block; visibility: hidden; width: 301px;">PD POWER POKER</span>
</div>
<div id="listitem12innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 600px; left: 0px;">
<span class="" style="display: block; visibility: hidden; width: 301px;">PROD Ray</span>
</div>
<div id="listitem13innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 624px; left: 0px;">
<span class="" style="display: block; visibility: hidden; width: 301px;">PT INTEGR</span>
</div>
<div id="listitem14innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 648px; left: 0px;">
<span class="" style="display: block; visibility: hidden; width: 301px;">Perfomance</span>
</div>
<div id="listitem15innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 672px; left: 0px;">
<span class="" style="display: block; visibility: hidden; width: 301px;">Piazza demo</span>
</div>
<div id="listitem16innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 696px;">
<span class="" style="visibility: hidden;"></span>
</div>
<div id="listitem17innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listitem-element" role="option" style="height: 24px; top: 720px;">
<span class="" style="visibility: hidden;"></span>
</div>
<div id="verticalScrollBarinnerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-scrollbar jqx-scrollbar-sandbox jqx-widget jqx-widget-sandbox jqx-widget-content jqx-widget-content-sandbox jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-sandbox" style="visibility: inherit; left: 311px; top: 0px; position: absolute; width: 15px; height: 280px;">
<div id="horizontalScrollBarinnerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-scrollbar jqx-scrollbar-sandbox jqx-widget jqx-widget-sandbox jqx-widget-content jqx-widget-content-sandbox jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-sandbox" style="visibility: hidden; left: 0px; top: 263px; position: absolute; height: 15px; width: 311px;">
<div id="bottomRightinnerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo" class="jqx-listbox-bottomright jqx-listbox-bottomright-sandbox" style="left: 312px; top: 659px; border: medium none; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; width: 18px; height: 18px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

PS: First we need to activate the droplist because it is hidden.

Answer (score 2):

First, open the dropdown by clicking on it.  I have no idea which element does that, but you should be able to do that.

To select/click on CORAL:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#listitem8innerListBoxjqxWidgetHostPortCombo span")).click();
```

If you don't know how to write selectors, though, Stackoverflow is NOT the place to ask other people to write them for you.  Please learn about the different selectors you can use with [`By`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html).  I would especially recommend taking the time to learn CSS.